# Notation from Bowen's Equilibrium States and the Ergodic Theory of Anosov Diffeomorphisms

Tags: notation, dynamical-systems

On pdf page 39 (page 33 of the [text](http://www.cpht.polytechnique.fr/sites/default/files/Bowen_LN_Math_470_second_ed_v2013.pdf)) under Proposition 2.8, the following notation was used

$$U(\underline{V})=U(V_{i_0})\cdots U(V_{i_{m-1}})$$
$$U(\Gamma_m)=\{U(\underline{V}):V\in \Gamma_m\}$$

I double checked through the earlier parts of the book and never came across an explanation for the $U(V)$ notation.  I thought at first the notation was to emphasize the choice of $U$ was a function of $V$ (i.e. "every $V\in \mathcal{V}$ lies in some $U(V)\in \mathcal{U}$").... but this just doesn't quite feel right.

Comment: Actually the bar on top of $V$ should go under it in both cases... I just don't know the LaTeX for this.

Comment: Your first thought was correct: The first sentence of the proof of Prop 2.8 defines $U(V)$ as an element of $\mathcal{U}$ that contains $V$.  As simple as that; nothing more.

Comment: BTW, tex for $\underline{V}$ is `\underline` in place of `\bar`